# Verilog - Shifting a register

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to write a parameter dependant FIFO using verilog.

To be specific, it depends on a word width M and queue length N.
I've started with implementing a 1 bit wide fifo.

I'm having trouble debugging it at the moment (which is the reason it's a bit messy, apologies!), when the main issue arises from dealing with the register bit_list.

while implementing this register I wish to shift it in order to pop out the value in bit_list[N-1], along with moving the rest of the register 1 bit towards N-1.

Unfortunately my implementation does not work and results with the errors: 
"Memory or an array reference requires an index [3.8][4.2.2(IEEE)]", along with 
"<< (left shift) operator left operand type illegal"
both in regards to the lines

```
bit_list=bit_list<<1;
```

(side comment: the first error also appeared regarding my commented "else" lines - before I commented them of course)

My code:

```
module single_fifo(clk,reset,in_bit,push,pop,out_bit,full);
   parameter N=4; // determines the maximum number of words in queue.
   input clk, reset, push, pop;
   input in_bit;
   output out_bit;

   reg bit_list [N-1:0];
   reg [N-1:0] n; 
   reg out_bit;
   output full;
   reg full;

   always @(posedge clk) 
   begin
    if (reset==1) begin
        n=0;
        bit_list=0;

    end
    else begin //reset==0
        if (n==0) begin             //n=0
            if (push==1) begin
                bit_list[N-1-n]=in_bit;
                n=n+1;
            end
            //else //push==0
            //  bit_list=bit_list;
        end else if ((n>0) && (n<N)) begin  //0<n<N
            if (pop==1) begin
                bit_list=bit_list<<1; //SHIFT DIREDCTION MIGHT BE FLIPPED
                n=n-1;
            end
            //else //pop==0
            //  bit_list=bit_list;

            if (push==1) begin
                bit_list[N-1-n]=in_bit;
                n=n+1;
            end
            //else //push==0
            //  bit_list=bit_list;
        end else begin              //n==N
            if (pop==1) begin
                bit_list=bit_list<<1; //SHIFT DIREDCTION MIGHT BE FLIPPED
                n=n-1;
                if (push==1) begin
                    bit_list[N-1-n]=in_bit;
                    n=n+1;
                end
            //  else //push==0
            //      bit_list=bit_list;
            end
            //else //pop==0
            //  bit_list=bit_list;
        end     
    end //reset==0

    if (n==N)
        full=1;
    else //n<N
        full=0;
    out_bit=bit_list[N-1];


    end
endmodule
```

As you might be able to tell I'm quite new to verilog, so sorry if this question seems noobish. Help will be greatly appriciated!

Comment: it will eliminate the error if you declare your *bit_list* as the following `reg [N-1:0] bit_list;` However, you have other issues, e.g. using blocking assignments incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach is rather unorthodox.

The most common and easy way to make a FIFO is using a memory, a read and a write pointer.

Most obvious deficiencies:

- In your code you start to look at 'push' but ignore that at the same time there could be a 'pop'.
- On a 'pop' you shift the list one location but you need N cycles for it to fall trough.
- You probably need some 'data valid' flag which each FIFO entry.
- You have a 'full' status but no 'empty' status. A receiver would not know when it can start reading
- I see no protection against writing to a full FIFO or reading from an empty one.
- This `bit_list=bit_list<<1;` will not work when you have wider data. You need a for-loop.

It is probably not what you want to hear, but I would recommend you abandon this approach and have a look at an existing FIFO with read and write pointers

Besides all that you should use non-blocking assignments in you `@(posedge clk)` section.

Comment: I designed this fifo the way I was instructed, anyway Serge answered my question, but I'll use the rest of your comments to improve my code. Thanks!